# How to burn FLAC to audio CD?

Tags: audio

I want to burn .flac files directly to an audio CD. Is there any (possibly free) OS X application to do this?

Comment: Did you research this any?

Comment: Yes, and as a result of that, I answered my question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net) is free and open source software, but it is a bit buggy. [LiquidCD](http://www.maconnect.ch/download/LiquidCD2.08.zip) is freeware, but I didn't encounter any issues while using it.

Comment: Which of these applications does allow the creation auf Audio CDs (suitable for any CD player) directly from FLAC?

Comment: Both, you can try them. :)

Comment: I'm not so sure.  I was using Burn and it worked, but upgraded to a new iMac and when I installed Burn on the new iMac, it would no longer handle FLAC files.  (And I have ffmpeg installed, so it's not that.)  No help on the forum or from an email to the developer.